# Probability problem involving a 4-sided biased die

Tags: probability, random-variables

The question is this:

You have a $4$ - sided biased die numbered from $1$ to $4$. The numbers from one to three are equally likely to land face up, but number four is twice as likely to land face up as each of the other numbers. Suppose you are playing a game using this die. **If you get an even number on the die, your score will be the same as the number observed, but if it is an odd number, your score will be the observed number minus $1$**. Let X denote the sum of scores obtained after throwing the die twice. What is the value of $P(X=6$)?

**My solution:

$1$) Computing probabilities for each outcome of the die:

Let P($1$) = P($2$) = P($3$) = k.

Then P($4$) = 2k.

Now, k + k + k + 2k = 1.

Therefore $k = \frac{1}{5}$.**

****2.) Random Variable $X$ can take values ${0,2,4,6,8}$.

Ways event ($X = 6$) can happen : ${(2,4),(3,4),(4,2),(4,3)}$.

P((2,4)) = (1/5)*(2/5) = 2/25

P((3,4)) = 2/25

P((4,3)) = 2/25

P((4,2)) = 2/25

Therefore, P(X = 6) = 2/25 + 2/25 + 2/25 + 2/25 = 8/25 = *0.32*.****

However, the official answer for this question is **0.152**, and I'm not able to figure out how. Please help me with this.

Comment: I believe you mistook (3, 4) and (4, 3) for (3, 3).

Comment: Note:  the way the rules read, you might find it simpler to say the die has faces $\{0,2,2,4\}$ and that you get the result shown on the face with no subtraction.

Comment: Let it also be known that $\frac{8}{25} = 0.32$.

Comment: I agree with your result.  Well, I agree that the answer is $\frac 8{25}$ which, as has been pointed out, $.32$ not $.16$   I don't see where the official answer is coming from.

Comment: I also agree with $8/25$. Notice that $0.152 = 19/125$; the $125$ in the denominator is $5^3$, which one would expect to appear if the die were thrown three times, not twice.

Comment: Is my computation for each individual outcome of the die okay?

Comment: You have omitted outcome (3,3). Seems answer is 9/25 = 0.36. // Seems 'official' answer is wrong. Wouldn't be the first time.// @lulu. Please have another look at this.

Comment: @BruceET  $(3,3)$ only gets you to $4$ since each roll of $3$ is rounded down to $1$.  At least that's how I read the rules.  The only possible outcomes on a single roll are $\{0,2,4\}$ with $2, 4$ each being twice as likely as $0$.

Comment: @lulu, I did have a different interpretation. So deleting my Answer. Thanks.